# Deploying Terraform (IaC) to Azure using Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I am currently trying to follow this link:

https://medium.com/@khandelwal12nidhi/integrate-terraform-with-jenkins-d283dd5d819c

But this is a deployment to AWS. There are really no documents on how to deploy a terraform template to Azure using Jenkins. While following the document I'm not sure what we should put in the environment variables considering theirs is going to link to AWS also I'm not even sure that the pipeline would work. Is this something that is even possible?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/ignite-2018-azure-devops-using-jenkins-terraform-and-ansible/)?

Comment: I would highly recommend not following that blog article you linked to, and instead try the one commented above.